# Django-ImageKit issue with ImageSpecField original image

Tags: python, django-models, imagekit, django-imagekit

ImageKit has given me quite the headache over the last few days. I had an internal server error on my site because I followed the example ImageSpecField on the [GitHub](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit) page:

```
avatar_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='avatar',
                                  processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                                  format='JPEG',
                                  options={'quality': 60})
```

The resultant error was:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'source'
```

So, I updated the avatar_thumbnail to use the example ImageSpecField on the [ReadTheDocs](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) page:

```
avatar_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(image_field='avatar',
                                  processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                                  format='JPEG',
                                  options={'quality': 60})
```

And then I got the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image_field'
```

It's odd that when I use 'source' the app will run locally successfully with no error. On the server the app runs with 'image_field' without an internal error, but still doesn't actually create or display the avatar image. Both the server and local have version 2.0.4 of django-imagekit installed.

Any advice would be wonderful.

Answer (score 4):

I'm one of the maintainers of ImageKit. I think the first issue is that you were looking at the docs for the development version (on GitHub), but using the latest stable release (from PyPI). The development version is currently 3.0b and some things have changed from the 2.x series—one of them being that the `image_field` argument was renamed to `source`. (Within the next week or so, we'll be dropping the "beta," pushing 3.0 to PyPI, and updating the "latest" docs on RTD.)

With that corrected, the thumbnail should be generated automatically when you access the thumbnail's url property (which is usually done in a template in order to display the image).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm upgrading my imagekit from 2.0.4 to 3.2.5(latest as of for now). I found the change from "image_field" to "source" as well, but there might be other changes that I'm not aware of. I couldn't find any changelogs from your website. Can you point me to some right resources? Thanks!